# transitionwithview works only half way

Tags: uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I ve made 2 views (one front , one back) and putted them inside another view called contain.
I just wanted to make a transition between the two views (front,back) by pressing a button.So i wrote the following code:

- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {

  [UIView transitionWithView:_contain

  ```
                duration:0.5
                 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight)
              animations:^{
                  if (a == NO) {

                      [_front removeFromSuperview];
                      [_contain addSubview:_back];

                      a = YES;

                  }else if (a == YES){

                      [_back removeFromSuperview];
                      [_contain addSubview:_front];

                      a = NO;
                  }
              }
              completion:nil];
  ```

}

The problem is that the first transition works flawless,but when we reach to then second transition (back to front) the transition takes place but instead of the front view i 've got the blank page of the contain view.And then the transition don't work when i press the button.Any advice?

Thank you.